# mod_rewrite is not being enabled?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos, centos5

I have php 5.3.8, apache 2.2.21, all is good, except mod_rewrite

by default `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` is enabled (not commented out)

`ClearModuleList` does not exist

`AddModule mod_rewrite.c` does not exist

and then you have

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

still i test mod_rewrite and it's not working, what more should i do?? if it wasn't for .htaccess i would have used nginx, by the way apache was installed by default when i got the vps and then i updated it but that didn't change the httpd.conf settings

do you think i should uninstall it and reinstall it by myself??? everyone say that mod_rewrite should not be enabled by default so i don't know why my apache is different

Comment: This question should be on serverfault.

Comment: @RaffaelLuthiger then please migrate it because i don't want to ask it twice and then be told that this is a duplicated question, it happened before :D

Comment: do you have any aliases? remove.

Comment: how did you test mod_rewrite? you need **RewriteEngine On** before **RewriteRule** in **httpd.conf** or **.htaccess**

Comment: @mido i don't have aliases

Comment: @cuttinger i tested my mod_rewrite like this Options +FollowSymLinks
  Redirect /google.html http://www.google.com

Comment: i tested it using many ways, i get this error: the url requested was not found on the server

Comment: redirect and rewrite are different topics

Comment: @Eli I do not have enough points to migrate it myself. I can only flag the questions. And that's what I did. I left this note to those who can migrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive belongs to `mod_alias`, not `mod_rewrite`.

To test the `mod_rewrite`, put the belows in `.htaccess` file in document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://google.com [R=301,L]
```

Make sure that you set `AllowOverride All` in `<Directory "/document/root">`

Comment: 302 responce, I suppose, is better in common

Comment: Smth. like `RewriteRule ^one.html$ two.html` is slightly better for local tests

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Load that page up in your web browser, and perform a search for “mod_rewrite”. All being well, you’ll find it in the “Apache loaded modules” section of the page.

.htaccess **before** any RewriteRule **must** have `RewriteEngine on`

The structure of a RewriteRule

RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [OptionalFlags]